# Can an ifstream variable be a global variable?

Tags: c++, ifstream

```
// stream from file.
ifstream file;

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {

// get argument passed from command line
// This is file name
if (argc != 2 ) {
    cout << "use:  ./executable <filename>";

}else {
    //cout << "You are using filename: " << argv[1];

    // start the file stream
    file (argv[1]);
}
```

Is there any reason why `file(argv[1])` would be giving an error? Can I have a ifstream as a global variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to call the `ifstream`'s `()` operator (which doesn't exist), when you should be using [`file.open(argv[1])`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/open/).

Besides that, there's nothing illegal about having a global `ifstream`.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't realize that the I was using a constructor. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Actually, he's calling `ifstream::operator()` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the ifstream as a global variable (whether this is good style is a different question).

The problem seems to be that you're attempting to use the constructor: `file(argv[1])`

The global variable would already be constructed (using the default constructor) at this point, and you will instead need to use the `open` method.

```
file.open( argv[1] );
```

Comment: Yes, I realize the use of a global variable is not necessary the best idea. For this project, it will be sufficient. Thank you for the additional explanation.